# How convert path point distance to real world distance?

Tags: ros, navigation, path-planning, rviz, path

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From navigation package ,I can get the a path to the goal.
but the points in the path are very close, I mean it is like: (45.0001 70.0002) , (45.0002 70.0003) ,(45.0003 70.0004) ...

and the distance between those points is very small value.

my question is : how convert this small value distance to real world distance with unit meter?

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54015/how-convert-path-point-distance-to-real-world-distance?/) by [redheli](https://answers.ros.org/users/3571/redheli/) on ROS Answers with karma: 68 on 2013-02-01

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Which message are listening for from the navigation package? If you are listening for [nav_msgs/Path](http://ros.org/doc/api/nav_msgs/html/msg/Path.html), the coordinates should be in meters. You should be able to get the total distance to the goal by adding up the small distances between the individual points.

---

Originally posted by [damjan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2702/damjan/) with karma: 446 on 2013-02-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [redheli](https://answers.ros.org/users/3571/redheli/) on 2013-02-02**:
Damjan, you are right. I subscribe the /path[nav_msgs/Path], and I calculate the total distance of the path points , the value is real meter distance. Thank you so much!

**Comment by [damjan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2702/damjan/) on 2013-02-11**:
Glad it helped! Could you please mark the answer as correct (by clicking on the checkmark to the left), so it shows up as answered in searches?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In general the coordinates are defined in a particular unit, so if u calculate distance between these points it should be in meters or whatever the unit is..

---

Originally posted by [ayush_dewan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2268/ayush_dewan/) with karma: 1610 on 2013-02-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [redheli](https://answers.ros.org/users/3571/redheli/) on 2013-02-02**:
Thank you shade. I realize ROS define the x,y,z coordinate in meter.